# Formatar campos monetários

Tags: jquery

Tenho um campo que contém uma máscara:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém preciso que no retorno, ele fique dessa forma:

**1212.12**

Tentei com o código abaixo, mas não funcionou:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="Valor" id="valor">
```

**JQuery**

```
var nValor = $("#valor").val().split('R$');
var novo = nValor[1].formatMoney(2, '.', ',');
```

Comment: Tem um plugin de JQuery que faz isso ai: https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney

Comment: Ou quer fazer no braço?

Comment: Olá Everson. No braço seria muito complicado? Pois seria para apenas um pequeno trecho de código e em uma única página.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

```
var valor = "R$ 11.000,00";
var nValor = valor.val().split('R$');
moedaFloat(nValor);
function moedaFloat(valor){
         moeda = moeda.replace(".","");
         moeda = moeda.replace(",",".");
         return parseFloat(moeda);
   }
```